# DiscordJS Music Bot Connects and Then Immediately Disconnects From Voice Channel

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, youtube, node-modules, discord.js

I see that questions similar to this one have been asked, and after following their solutions I still end up the same as I started. Below I have listed my code, a link to test it with a sample bot I created, and the modules you will need to test it using a self-hosted instance.

My problem is that upon connecting to the specified voice channel, the bot immediately leaves afterwards without any signs of errors or exceptions. I'm not sure if it is a problem with my code, or with one of the libraries I am using. The only console output I receive is as follows:

```
Bot Ready For Use
joined channel
left channel
```

Thanks!

> My Code

```
var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;

if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send(`You do realize you have to be in a voice channel to do that, right ${message.author.username}?`)

if (!message.member.voiceConnection) voiceChannel.join().then(async connection => {

    let streamURL = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    let streamTitle = "";
    let streamThumb = "";
    let streamAuth = "";
    let streamAuthThumb = "";

    if (streamURL.includes("https://www.youtube.com") || streamURL.includes("https://youtu.be/") && !streamURL.includes(' ')) {
        let results = await youtube.getVideo(streamURL)

        let {
            body
        } = await snekfetch.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=${results.channel.id}&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Fthumbnails&key=${ytapikey}`).query({
            limit: 800
        })

        streamTitle = results.title
        streamThumb = results.thumbnails.medium.url
        streamAuth = results.channel.title
        streamAuthThumb = body.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url

    } else if (!streamURL.includes("https://www.youtube.com") || !streamURL.includes("https://youtu.be/")) {

        let results = await youtube.searchVideos(streamURL)

        let {
            body
        } = await snekfetch.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=${results[0].channel.id}&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Fthumbnails&key=${ytapikey}`).query({
            limit: 800
        })

        streamURL = results[0].url
        streamTitle = results[0].title
        streamThumb = results[0].thumbnails.medium.url
        streamAuth = results[0].channel.title
        streamAuthThumb = body.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url

    } else {
        return message.reply("I can only play videos from YouTube (#NotSponsored).")
    }

    console.log("joined channel");
    const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOMhN-hfMtY', {
        filter: 'audioonly'
    });
    const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, {
        seek: 0,
        volume: 1
    });
    dispatcher.on("end", end => {
        console.log("left channel");
        voiceChannel.leave();
    });

    let musicEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(streamAuth, streamAuthThumb)
        .setTitle(`Now Playing:`)
        .addField(`${streamAuth}`, `${streamTitle}`)
        .setImage(streamThumb)
        .setColor(embedRed)
        .setFooter(`${streamAuth} - ${streamTitle} (${streamURL}`)

    message.channel.send(musicEmbed)

}).catch(console.error);
break
```

> List of Modules

```
discord.js
simple-youtube-api
node-opus
ffmpeg
ffbinaries
ffmpeg-binaries
opusscript
snekfetch
node-fetch
ytdl-core
```

Click [here](https://repl.it/@raw/stackoverflow) to use my sample bot through [repl.it](https://repl.it/).

Thanks Again!

Comment: Have you tried it with multiple videos? Just to make sure it's not the video itself.

Comment: You also might try logging the reason your dispatcher is ending (you're variable named 'end') to the console and see if that offers anything useful.  The dispatcher also has an error event.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell I have tried a whopping 10 and made sure they all had audio.

Comment: @Tarazed I have tried that and its just exiting normally.

Comment: Could you tell us what it logged?

Comment: Nothing. It logged nothing besides what I already have.